# flask-security can't work with gunicorn with multiple workers?

Tags: python, nginx, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn, flask-security

I'm writing a website with `Flask`. I use `Flask-Secuirty` to do authentication. I use `nginx + gunicorn` to deploy it.

The configuration of nginx as follow:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name project.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And I use `gunicorn -w worker_number -k gevent run:app -p app.pid -b 127.0.0.1:5000` to start `gunicorn`.

If the `worker_number` is `1`, everything is ok.

If the `worker_number` is greater than `1` like `3`, I can't login in with `Flask-Security`.

The output of server said the post request of login is 200. But the server redirect me to login page again.

After some search, I can't find direct reason of this. And I guess this might cause by `SERVER_NAME` config of Flask or the misuse of `Flask-SQLAlchemy`.

Is there anyone has met this situation before? Please give me some advices.

Answer (score 9):

I met a similar problem with flask_login, when the worker_number is greater than 1, I could not login in.

My app.secret_key was set to os.urandom(24), so every worker will have another secret key.

Set app.secret_key to a string solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a fixed secret key.
Generate with following command.
`$ openssl rand -base64 <desired_length>`

If you don't want to hardcode the key inside source code which you shouldn't for security purposes.
Set up an environment variable and get it.

```py
import os

# -- snip --

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("FLASK_APP_SECRET_KEY")
```

Comment: This would be the accepted answer. Solves the problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) and use Redis as a session store. I'm not sure how Flask-Security works, but I assume it relies on Flask sessions, in which case it would solve the problem of a user session switching between application servers.